# How can I impersonate the current user with IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, iis-7

I am trying to manage an IIS7 installation remotely using the Microsoft.Web.Administration library.

I'm doing this in IronPython:

```
import Microsoft.Web.Administration
from Microsoft.Web.Administration import ServerManager

manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServerName")
for site in manager.Sites:
     print "Site: %(site)s" % { 'site' : site.Name }
```

On the last line as it attempts to communicate with the remote server I get the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   remote component with CLSID
>   {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344}
>   from machine devdealernetsvr failed
>   due to the following error: 80070005.

My research into the error lead me to believe that I do not have the proper credentials against the remote machine and so I would like to impersonate a user that does.

I was hard pressed to find a way to do this with IronPython. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Even though I "answered" my own question I would still love to hear something from someone else about how to do the impersonation. Maybe I'll get around to solving that one day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this doesn't necessarily answer the question but it does fix the problem)

It turned out my application worked fine. My setup was the problem. :(

To fix my issue I needed to:

1. Log into the remote server.
2. In IIS enable remote management (it's just a check box)
3. In the Services snap-in, start the remote management service and set it to automatic

Thanks Anthony!